# Audio in screencast recordings out-of-sync when using USB Headphones

Tags: usb, audio, screen-capture, headphones

When I record **screencasts** on my laptop with **USB headphones**, the audio increasingly **lags** behind the video.

However when I record with my **built-in** laptop microphone, there is **no lag**.

I have tried recording with both **Camtasia** as well as **Hypercam 2**, each give the same results.

I have tried **3 different USB headphones**, each give the same results. All USB headphones are made by **Plantronics**.

I unfortunately have **no microphone audio jack** on my laptop (only a headphone jack) so cannot test non-USB headphones.

I also downloaded the 32-bit version of Hypercam instead of the 64-bit version, with same results.

My laptop is:

- Dell Latitude E6420
- Windows 7, 64-bit
- Intel Core i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz
- 8 GB

**What could be causing this lag to occur when recording with USB headphones and how do I fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a workaround for this:

When I record the video in a Windows XP (32-bit) virtual machine running on the above Windows 7, 64-bit machine, using the same USB headphones plugged into the Windows XP's virtual USB port, there is no lag.